# Proof of function property in group theory

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The question states:
Consider a function $f: S\rightarrow S$. Let $f(A) = \{f(x)|x \in A\}$ and $f(B) = \{f(x)|x \in B\}$. Prove that if $A \subseteq B \subseteq S$ then $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$.

The solution states:

$B \subseteq S $ and $f : S\rightarrow S \Rightarrow f(B) \subseteq$ range of $B$

Now if $f(x) \in f(A)$

$\Rightarrow x \in A$

$\Rightarrow x \in B $ {as $A \subseteq B$}

$\Rightarrow f(x) \in f(B)$

Thus $f(x) \in f(B)$ for all $x \in A$

Hence, $f(x) \in f(A) \Rightarrow f(x) \in f(B)$.

Thus $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$.

What is the point of the first line of this solution?

Comment: This is definitely not a question related to group theory.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 I am sorry this is from an introductory group theory textbook. Perhaps the basics aren't considered group theory yet? If so, please do not hesitate to change the title and tags

Comment: what is the date of your book ? sometimes old books refer to range as the codomain, while nowadays there is no distinction between the image $f(B)$ and the range of $B$. Anyway, this line seems superfluous to me as well.

Comment: @zwim It is a new book. They say that the range is a subset of the codomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y \in f(A).$  Then $\exists$ $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = y.$ Now $A \subseteq B$ and $x \in A \implies x \in B.$ Therefore $y = f(x) \in f(B).$ This shows that $f(A) \subseteq f(B).$

Comment: maybe, but that is not the question asked.

Comment: I understand that part of the solution, but I am wondering why the book's solution begins with $B \subseteq S $ and $f : S\rightarrow S \Rightarrow f(B) \subseteq$ range of $B$ Is that line necessary to the validity of the proof or is it superfluous?

Comment: Actually $f(B) =$ range of $B$ under the function $f \subseteq S.$

Comment: It is clear that the argument in your book is wrong because $f(x) \in f(A) \not\implies x \in A.$

Comment: @Dbchattoo67 I agree with your first point, but this book does seem quite fond of using $\subseteq$ instead of =.

Comment: @Dbchattoo67 As for you second point, as the relation is a function, doesn't it make that statement correct?

Comment: Nope. Take the function $f(x) = 0,$ for all $x \in \Bbb R.$ Consider the set $A = \Bbb Z.$ Then it is clear that $f(x) \in f(A) = \{0 \}.$ Does it necessarily imply that $x \in A$?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 That is true. I had not realized. Out of curiosity, if they had specified that the function was an injection, then the statement would be true, right? Now is it possible to write a valid proof or is the question flawed?

Comment: If the function was injective then definitely the proof in your book works. But it is not the case then you can proceed along the lines of my answer which I think is a valid proof of your question.